# Using AddressBookUI.framework with a different backend?

Tags: ios, objective-c, addressbookui

Is it possible to use the AddressBookUI.framework but with a different database to store the data in.

I'd like to keep the look & feel of the "contacts" app, but don't want the data to be stored in the default address book.

Answer (score 0):

We use the AddressBookUI.framework for displaying contacts, but have our own database. We have a translation middleman which translates our own objects into `ABPersonRef` objects and vice versa. You can then pass the reference to a person view controller or an unknown person view controller. This does not require the permission of the user to access the contacts, because you can create the temporary `ABPersonRef` into empty address books.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I'll see if I can get things working that way.